# Getting null from output value in sqldatasource updated event from storedprocedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

I can't figure out why do i keep getting null from stored procedure... I'm doing exactly the same thing on an insert in a different sqldatasource and I'm getting the scope_identity returned, yet on an update i cannot get the value returned...

This is the stored procedure. I tried remove set nocount on even and didn't change anything

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UPDATE_ADefinicao_Extrusao]
@RegistoID int,
@Base_Cru varchar(50),
@Linha_Cru varchar(5),
@Diametro_Cru numeric(6,2),
@Espessura_Cru numeric(6,2),
@Comprimento_Cru numeric(6,2),
@Marcacao_Continua_Cru varchar(max),
@ID int = null OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE RVFC_Definicao
SET [Base_Cru] = @Base_Cru, [Linha_Cru] = @Linha_Cru, [Diametro_Cru] = 
@Diametro_Cru, [Espessura_Cru] = @Espessura_Cru, 
    [Comprimento_Cru] = @Comprimento_Cru, [Marcacao_Continua_Cru] = 
@Marcacao_Continua_Cru, [Data_Registo_Extrusao] = 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),105)
WHERE ID_Registo = @RegistoID

SET @ID = @RegistoID
SELECT @ID -- Update successful

END
```

and my sqldatasource, i tried setting Size for the varchars but doesn't change anything cause i'm not even doing this on the insert one.

```
          <asp:SqlDataSource
                ID="sdsADefinicao"
                runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ValidacaoFormas_ConnectionString %>"
                UpdateCommand="sp_UPDATE_ADefinicao_Extrusao"
                UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
                OnUpdated="sdsADefinicao_Updated"
                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
                SelectCommand="sp_SELECT_ADefinicao">

                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdfRegistoID" Name="RegistoID" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>

                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="fvADefinicao" Name="RegistoID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Base_Cru" Type="String" Size="50" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Linha_Cru" Type="String" Size="5" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Diametro_Cru" Type="Decimal" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Espessura_Cru" Type="Decimal" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Comprimento_Cru" Type="Decimal" />                        
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Marcacao_Continua_Cru" Type="String"/>                                                                                                
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" Direction="Output" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and codebehind to get value

```
   protected void sdsADefinicao_Updated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        int registoID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters["@ID"].Value);

        FileUpload fuAnexo = fvADefinicao.FindControl("fuAnexo") as FileUpload;

        int numFiles = fuAnexo.PostedFiles.Count;
        int index = 0;
        Ficheiro[] files = new Ficheiro[numFiles];

        foreach (HttpPostedFile file in fuAnexo.PostedFiles)
        {
            Ficheiro anexo = new Ficheiro("HUTMATER");
            anexo.Nome = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            using (Stream fs = file.InputStream)
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                anexo.Dados = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            }
            files[index] = anexo;
        }

        string piloto = SessionManager.Nome;
        Ficheiro.Upload(Convert.ToInt32(registoID), piloto, files); // Guarda anexos do formulario na base de dados            
    }
```

Comment: How does selecting the value of `@ID` confirm that the update was successful? It'll have the value of whatever was passed for `@RegistoID`, regardless of if any rows were updated. Also, I'd avoid using `CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),105)`. Always declare the length of your datatypes. *(That SQL also strongly implies that `[Data_Registo_Extrusao]` is a `varchar`, which is another concern, considering it's storing a date.)*

Comment: Why are you doing `SELECT @ID` when `@ID` is already an output parameter?  I can almost guarantee that you are not handling the return from the INSERT in the same way.   Why don't you show us that code?

Comment: I'm using ID just to return the record ID as a way to know it was updated successfully and i print a message with the ID after and thanks for the notice. I forgot to add size to varchar

Comment: Why do you need to output the same value you passed in? You already know the value in your code.

Comment: A slight detour but the sp_ prefix is reserved and should be avoided. Either use a different prefix, or even better no prefix at all. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally found the answer. It wasn't easy, everything was correct except the real exception was being hidden by a null reference. It seems like for some reason on the parameters I was sending were giving me a too many parameters exception.

```
@RegistoID and @ID_Registo
```

However I have no idea why since I never had any @ID_Registo parameter, that's just the column name on database. After changing the parameter name to @ID_Registo i was able to return a value from stored procedure.

If anyone has this problem, try changing parameter names to the same as the column names in database